# Auto-completion for python in Gedit3

Tags: python, autocomplete, ubuntu-14.04, gedit

I am using ROS in my Ubuntu 14.04. I want to enable auto-completion for python scripts.

I searched on internet but the results does not work on gedit 3.

Please note that the primary aim is to use ROS.

Comment: Any suggestion please?